# Joystick support in Java

Tags: java, joystick

Are there any libraries out there allowing access to joystick input in Java?

The minimum requirements would be for it to work under Windows, to be able to detect all connected joysticks and to handle axes and buttons.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try JInput https://github.com/jinput/jinput

It works even on Linux :)

Comment: I was wondering why my searches didn't turn up more libraries but it seems as jinput covers everything and is very simple to use. Thanks.

Comment: @D.S.Schneider I don't know about others OSs, but sadly I needed to change the permissions of the /dev/inputXX every time (not so simple)

Comment: @D.S.Schneider "Even on Linux" was probably referring back to my question, where I stated I wanted it to work on Windows, not to how difficult it is to do on Linux in general.

Comment: @Ferrybig it was 5 years old answer, links die. It seems they moved to github. Answer edited.