# What are the key codes for macro keys on gaming keyboards?

Tags: java, keyboard-events, keyevent

I'm looking for the key codes for G1-G18 macro keys on gaming keyboards, ie Corsair K90 Keyboard or Logitech Gaming Keyboards.
I would like to put global key listeners on those set of keys in C++.

G1-G18 are not part of the standard multimedia key code list.

Test Code in Java:

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
 System.out.println("Keycode pressed: "+e.getKeyCode());

}
```

This will never get key events when I press any of the G1-G18 macro keys. I want to be able to get key events from those keys.

Comment: AFAIK there are none. Those keys are programmed at the keyboard level to send sequences of standard keys.

Comment: Is this about Java or C++? I don't understand. And did you try `MouseListener`?

Answer (score 3):

Macro keys are usually proprietary keys sent along to the driver of your keyboard that perform some action hard-coded by the management software itself.

Because of this, the *system* doesn't actually handle any of those events.

If you need to interface with macro keys, look for the manufacturer's SDK or header includes for such things. It's not uncommon for them to be shipped with the management utility; look in the directory where the utility application resides and check for C/C++ header files. You'll need to write JNI bindings or use JNA in order to use them with Java, though.

---

The best you're going to get with such keys without directly interfacing with the driver is to set them up to run a specific macro sequence that the system *will* dispatch to Java, and to have a reaction within your Java program for that particular sequence. It's a hack, yes, but those keys weren't intended to be used in such a way (normally).

---

It's also not unheard of for these keys to be implemented as [joystick interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302764/joystick-support-in-java), so it might be worth it to check if they're being sent in such a manner. If they are, then that is probably how you'd want to interface with them.

Comment: Just to log, i.e i have fantech keyboard in 2021 with gkeys. company doesn't make drivers for linux (ubuntu in my case). running 'xev' command and capturing keycodes input in terminal. then key-mapper utility to change keys to joystick (with hope) works.
but i.e in blender i tried mapping those actions and blender says, keyboard input not supported :) ahh